# dependencies provided by weblogic

Tags: java, maven, weblogic

I'm playing with the Weblogic 12.1.3.0 server, but I'd like to now, which dependencies can be marked in my pom as provided. So the question is, where can I find full list of dependencies and its versions, which are provided by weblogic?

I found pom of weblogic under this identifiers:

```
  <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
  <artifactId>weblogic-server-pom</artifactId>
  <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

but in my opinion the list of dependencies, provided by this pom, doesn't show all of dependencies which weblogic provides.

I searched on a oracle website as well, but without any satisfying result.

Comment: What if you located directory(-ies) where WebLogic holds its jar files? You could consider those as "provided" by WebLogic. Then it is needed to map available jar files to GAV coordinates of maven artefacts.

Comment: Related to @scrutari's comment; try the `${your-wls-home}/server/modules` dir (or something like that).

Answer (score 2):

You can find all libraries inside weblogic at the following path:

```
$Middleware_Home/oracle_common/modules
```

From this list you can check the libraries and then check the maven-coordinate on-line.

Answer (score 0):

The third party JARs have mostly been renamed from their distribution, so it's hard to straight up use the WebLogic installation directory as a reference to what WebLogic offers runtime.

What might answer the question is the list of third party libraries in WebLogic 12c: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50629_01/core/ASTPL/thirdparty.htm#sthref5 - but this does not include version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I would rely on multiple sources and not just from Weblogic.  For example from Oracle.